# Nodemailer - AWS EC2 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nodemailer

I've googled for quite some time trying to figure out how to fix this issue and can't seem to get anywhere.

AWS EC2 Running Ubuntu
Security Group has 465 and 587 Open. unless i need to add something somewhere else.

here is my Nodemailer function.

```
    async function sendEmail({ from, to, subject, html})
    {
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
        clientId,
        secret, // Client Secret
        "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground" // Redirect URL
    );
    
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
            refresh_token: refresh
    })
    
    
    const accessToken = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken();
    
    const smtpTransport = await nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: '465',
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            type: "OAuth2",
            user: "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM",
            clientId: clientId,
            clientSecret: secret,
            refreshToken: refresh,
            accessToken: accessToken
    
        }
    })

    await smtpTransport.verify((err, success) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
    else
     console.log('Your config is correct');
    });

    const transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport);
    console.log(transporter);
    await transporter.sendMail({from,to,subject,html},(error,response)=>{ // Errors Here
        error ? console.log(error) : console.log(response);
        //smtpTransport.close();

    });
}

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

and below is the error code:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

Comment: Is the email address a gsuite user?

Comment: purchased an email to use with our custom domain name.

Comment: Purchased from Google? When logged in, does it say G Suite at the top right corner?

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky it is not a gsuite. and yes  it was purchased from google

Comment: Ok. I am not clear about what you did. If you purchased an email from google, I would imagine that is a G suite user. So I am confused. The reason I ask is that with G Suite, you can create a Service Account and then you need to enabe Domain Wide Delegation in admin.google.com

Comment: it was gsuite i switched to AWS ses to see if that would work just using plan SMTP still getting the same errors. i opened the outgoing ports for it. but to me its off that when i specify a port it just goes to the default 587

Comment: Why not open all outgoing traffic? And disable fw to test

Comment: outgoing is set to allow all still same error message :/